# What steps would one have to go through to change a program with char arrays to Strings in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so in my program I have to make a dumbed down version of Monopoly called Opoly. Its a basic program with a few simple rules

1. If your board piece lands on a board cell that is evenly divisible
   by 7, your reward doubles.
2. If you land on the final board cell, you must go back 3 spaces. Thus
   if the board size is 20, the last position is position 19, and if
   you land there, you should go back to position 16. (If the position
   of the last cell is evenly divisible by 7, no extra points are
   added, but if the new piece location, 3 places back, IS evenly
   divisible by 7, then extra points ARE added).
3. If you make it all the way around the board, you get 100 points.
   Note that if you land exactly on location 0, you first receive 100
   extra points (for making it all the around), and then your score is
   doubled, since 0 is evenly divisible by 7,
4. Every tenth move (that is, every tenth spin of the spinner, move
   numbers 10,20,30,... etc.), reduces the reward by 50 points. This
   penalty is applied up front, as soon as the 10th or 20th or 30th
   move is made, even if other actions at that instant also apply.
   Notice that with this rule it's possible for the reward amount to
   become negative.

I have done this successfully. However, now my teacher wants us to do the same thing using Strings instead of a char Array. So I know a String is virtually a char array so what stepts would i have to take to make this really painless.

here is my code is you need something visual. I commented most of the code to help understanding it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class OpolyDriver{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter an int > 3 - the size of the board");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int boardSize = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Board Size: " + boardSize);
    Opoly g = new Opoly(boardSize);
    g.playGame();
  }
}

public class Opoly{

  private static int size; //how big the board is
  private static int spin; //value of the spinner
  private static int reward; //total points
  private static int turnNumber; //how many turns have passed
  private static char[] board; //the array of the board and holding the position of the player
  private static boolean first; //temp variable to create the array with *'s and o

  public Opoly(int s){ //constructor
    size = s; //sets the size passed by the main method defined by the user
    reward = 100; //startes player with 100 points
    turnNumber = 0; //sets turn number to 0
    board = new char[size]; //creates the array
    first = true; //temp variable to create the array with *'s and o
  }

  public void playGame(){
    Opoly.drawBoard(); //prints out board for the first time
    while (Opoly.isGameOver()){ //checks when the player has recieved 1000 points or more
      Opoly.spinAndMove(); //spins, moves, and adds points
      Opoly.drawBoard(); //prints out the updated board and reward
    }
    Opoly.displayReport(); //displays the stats when the game is over
  }

  public static void spin(){
    spin = (1 + (int)(Math.random() * 5)); //generates a number from 1 to 5
  }

  public static void move(){
    if (turnNumber % 10 == 0) //RULE #4 - Every tenth move, reduces the reward by 50 points.
      reward = reward - 50;

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++){ //finds the position of the player
      if (board[k] == 'o'){
        board[k] = '*';

        if (k == (size - 1)){ //RULE #2 (condition 1) - If you land on the final board cell, you must go back 3 spaces.
          board[k] = '*';
          board[k - 3] = 'o';
          if (((k - 3) % 7 == 0) && (k - 3 != 0)) //RULE #2 (condition 2 & 3) - If the position of the last cell is evenly divisible by 7, no extra points are added. If the new piece location, 3 places back, IS evenly divisible by 7, then extra points ARE doubled
            reward = reward * 2;

          if (((k - 3) + spin) >= size){ //brings the array back in bounds to cirlce the position of the player
            board[k - 3] = '*';
            reward = reward + 100; //RULE #3 - If you make it all the way around the board, you get 100 points.
            board[((k - 3) + spin) - size] = 'o';
          }
          else if (((k - 3) + spin) <= size){ //moves the position when player is in bounds of array
            board[k - 3] = '*';
            board[(k - 3) + spin] = 'o';
          }
        }
        else if ((k + spin) >= size){ //brings the array back in bounds to cirlce the position of the player
          reward = reward + 100; //RULE #3 - If you make it all the way around the board, you get 100 points.
          board[(k + spin) - size] = 'o';
        }
        else if ((k + spin) <= size) //moves the position when player is in bounds of array
          board[k + spin] = 'o';

        k = size; //resets k 
      }
    }
  }

  public static void spinAndMove(){
    turnNumber++; //adds a turn
    Opoly.spin(); //sets a number to the spin variable
    Opoly.move(); //moves the position
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++){ //adds points 
      if (board[k] == 'o'){
        if (k == 0) //RULE #1 - Score is doubled, since 0 is evenly divisible by 7,
          reward = reward * 2;
        else if ((k % 7 == 0) && (k != (size - 1))) //RULE #1 - Score is doubled when it is evenly divisible by 7,
          reward = reward * 2;
      }
    }
  }

  public static boolean isGameOver(){
    boolean isOver = true; //checks if game is over
    if (reward >= 1000) //if the reward is 1000 points or over than the game is over
      isOver = false;
    return isOver;
  }

  public static void drawBoard(){
    if (first){ //temp variable is used to create the board for the first time
      board[0] = 'o';
      for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        board[i] = '*';
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) //for loop that prints out the updated board
      System.out.print(board[i]);

    System.out.println(" " + reward); //prints out the reward

    first = false; //temp variable set to flase so it wont recreate the board again
  }

  public static void displayReport(){ //displays stats
    System.out.println("game over"); 
    System.out.println("rounds of play: " + turnNumber);
    System.out.println("final reward: " + reward);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or do you just want us to do it for you?

Comment: you cannot. arrays are mutable, when strings are not. You'd need to recreate the string every time you change a single letter.

Comment: @Dom If you read the question "What steps would one have to go through to change a program with char arrays to Strings in java?" Im asking what steps would one take. not do my homework

Comment: Well, first go visit the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) web page and read all the functions that are there.  Then observe that there's a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class which does most of what String does but is "mutable".  Seems to me that's all you should need to know to do a fairly literal translation.

Comment: @njzk2 - Not with StringBuilder.

Comment: another issue remains. Even with StringBuilder, charAt crashes if there is not enough content. Here, the char[] is initialized with a size, but is not given content. This behaviour cannot be reproduced out of the box by a StringBuilder.

Comment: my bad, the array is initialized in drawBoard (very bad practice, btw), so this should be feasible. (it still wouldn't make sense, though).

Comment: what I don't understand is why use a char[] to store o and *, when all you really need is the player position ?

Comment: @njzk2 what do you mean? how would i do that?

Comment: @njzk2 if you add an answer, ill give you rep. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does not really answers the question, so this can be removed if needs be.

Your `board` contains 2 types of values: `o` and `*`. The player, and not the player.

When you loop on the board array and test `if (board[k] == 'o'){`, what you are really doing is finding `k` such as k is the position of the player.

When you are modifying the board array, `board[k - 3] = 'o';` what you are really doing is affecting `k - 3` to the position of the player.

The position of the player can be represented as an integer, default value 0, and that should stay bounded between 0 and `size - 1`.

Typically, you would replace those

```
for (int k = 0; k < size; k++){
    if (board[k] == 'o') {
        // ...
    }
}
```

blocks by simply using `playerPosition` instead of `k`, and the

```
board[k] = '*';
board[<someValue>] = 'o';
```

by simply `playerPosition = <someValue>;` where  is `k - 3`, `k + spin`...